# Angular ng-click="function()" not firing but (click)="function()" does

Tags: angularjs, click, angularjs-ng-click

Working on angular project where i need to execute a function on an element clicked
using ng-click. Using ng-click on any element won't fire the function except when i use (click) eg
  Box 1   -- this does not work
  Box 1    -- this works

so where exactly is ng-click useful?

Thank You

Comment: Can you post your markup please and controller function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161489/ngclick-deprecated-popular-alternative-or-solution

Comment: ng-click was for AngularJS. Angular 2 onwards (Angular) user (click) or similar to register event handlers.

Comment: OK. Exactly what i wanted to know. Use (click) instead of ng-click in Angular. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `ng-click` in Angular.

Perhaps you're looking for `on-click="function()"

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax lists the canonical forms for bindings.

Comment: "There is no ng-click in Angular" Do you mean in angular 2? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: No, I mean Angular, and yes I mean Angular 2,4,5, .... What you mean is AngularJS ;-) The question has the `angular` tag, but you might be right, that in fact it should have the `angularjs` tag instead.

Comment: As far as I know there is no `(click)="..."` in AngularJS, therefore I think it has to be Angular (2,4,5).

Comment: Good recovery ;)